Extend or replace compiled library enum
I have a web application developed with Kotlin/Spring Boot and an external library which is successfully injected with Gradle. The project itself works fine.
However, I need one more value in an enum class of that library. Obviously, I can't just add it there, because it's already compiled.
What is the best way to do it? Should I use bytecode editor or inject my own changed version of this library?
I tried to write an enum class inside my project with the same pakage structure. It works fine while compiling the project (I can add new value to the enum and use it), but at runtime I catch java.lang.NoSuchFieldError. Also exclusion of the module of the library doesn't help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

You can not add more value if the library does not expect it. You have to rewrite corresponding library classes that work with this enum too.

Do you really need that though or is it just "convenience" because you don't want to setup sealed class that wraps said enum or your custom values

The point of an enum is that it has a fixed set of possible values. If you could do this, the library would have unexpected bugs and crashes when it fails to account for the new value or tries to use it in its own code. This is why the only way you could safely do it is to fork the library as mentioned in talex's answer. Then you need to check every place that enum is used inside the library and make sure it is appropriately handling the new case(s).

Most straight forward way is to fork that library and change enum source code.
Then build it and use result.
Only work if library licence allows it.

Thanks! Already started to change the library's source code, because there is no easy and proper way to change compiled enum class. Fortunately, the license of the lib allow me to do this.
